# Reversing the order of a CSS hover transition

Tags: html, css, overlay, mouseover

I want to create an effect on some boxes. On mouse an overlay has to appear and after a fraction of a second later the title and then subtitle. So far so good, but I wish that when I remove the mouse the elements will disappear in the reverse order in which they entered. How would I do this?

```
.overlayPortfolio {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.overlayPortfolio h1 {
    color: #292929;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.sectionSubtitle {
    color: #292929;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .9s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .9s ease-out;
    transition: all .9s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.9s;
    transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

As you can see the overlay appears after 0.3 seconds, then the title and as the last the subtitle.
All is ok on mouseon, but at mouseout all disappear at the same time :(

What went wrong?

Comment: Simply give :hover css the transition delay you currently have, and invert it in the regular css

Comment: Consider posting this as an answer @Aarilight

Comment: Yes, with example code.

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't have the html you were using, I went ahead and wrote up a simpler example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aarilight/9srcww1o/)

The html:

```
<div id="hoverable">
    <div id="e1"></div>
    <div id="e2"></div>
    <div id="e3"></div>
</div>
```

First we write the initial CSS:

```
#hoverable {
    height:60px;
}
#hoverable * {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    background:black;
    transition: margin-top .3s ease-in-out;
}

#hoverable:hover * {
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Now all of the boxes have a smooth transition moving down.

Next, we add the delays:

```
#hoverable #e2 {
    transition-delay: .3s;
}
#hoverable #e3 {
    transition-delay: .6s;
}
```

Finally, to invert the delays, we have to add separate styles for when the `#hoverable` element is being hovered on.

```
#hoverable:hover #e1 {
    transition-delay: .6s;
}
#hoverable:hover #e3 {
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

This makes it so that when you're hovering over the element, it uses the transition delay for the in-direction, and when you hover off of it, it removes that style, making it use the default delay. In this case, since `#e2` is always the second element to move, its delay is always `.3s`. It was simply a matter of inverting the delays of `#e1` and `#e3`

Also, the reason your elements all disappear at once is because your elements are all inside of the first element you want to be transitioned. When your parent element hides itself, since it's containing the child ones, they disappear with it. If they weren't the children of the first element, they wouldn't all disappear at once. Still wouldn't be the reverse order tho. =)

As a side note, there are some things you can make simpler in your css.

If you head to the [`transition` page on CanIuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), you can see that there are no vendor prefixes on almost all modern versions. That means you don't need to do the `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, and `-o-` stuff anymore. =)

Also, I personally am not fond of using `transition: all`, as it's not very easy to tell what you want to transition specifically. I would recommend specifying each thing you want to transition, like this, for example:

```
transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, color .3s ease-in-out, margin .3s ease-in-out;
```